# Mirrored print DataGrid

Tags: c#, printing, persian, modern-ui

My Platform is ModernUI
I want to print my DataGrid 
But result is mirrored! like when you see a word at the mirror.

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="LT_Persons" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="auto" FontFamily="B        Nazanin" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" CanUserAddRows="False" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <DataGrid.Columns></DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
<Button Name="Print" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,30,25,22" Content="پرینت" Click="Print_Click" Width="55" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

C#

```
 private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrintVisual(LT_Persons, "افراد");
    }
```